# Simple mpi4py example fails

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I have tried running the following code for sending and receiving python objects using mpi4py from http://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    data = {'a': 7, 'b': 3.14}
    comm.send(data, dest=1, tag=11)
elif rank == 1:
    data = comm.recv(source=0, tag=11)
```

but it produces the following error on rank one trying to receive:

```
  File "send.py", line 11, in <module>
    data = comm.recv(source=0, tag=11)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1192, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.recv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:106889)
  File "MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 264, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_recv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:42691)
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_INTERN: internal error
```

I'm using Python 3.4.2

Anyone know why this could be?

Thanks!

Comment: What command do you use to run the program? do you use `mpirun`?

Comment: mpirun -np 2 --oversubscribe python send.py

Comment: works fine when I do essentially the same thing, but the send/recv is of numpy arrays.

Comment: The example works for me and I don't see anything wrong. Maybe there is something wrong with your MPI installation...

Comment: Could it be that you are using infiniband?